# Does camunda have rest api for authentication

Tags: camunda, bpmn, business-process-management, camunda-plugin, camunda-spin

> Is there rest api to use for login and logout in camunda rest api.

I want to create stand alone front end for camunda. The problem is how can i authnticate a user via rest api of camunda engin ???

Answer (score 1):

From the Caunda User Guide:

> https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/security/
>
> **Deployment Options and Components**
>
> - Embedded Java library inside an application: in this case, the Camunda engine is embedded inside a custom Java Application. Usually
>   the application takes care of securing access to Camunda’s APIs and
>   the APIs are not directly exposed to an end user. In this case, the
>   application typically takes care of ensuring authentication and
>   preventing access by unauthorized users.
> - Shared Process Engine: in this scenario, the Process Engine is deployed as a container service into an application server such that
>   it can be used by the applications deployed into the same container /
>   server. This case is similar to the embedded Java library case.
> - REST API: the REST API provides access to Camunda’s core APIs through HTTP. In this case users can directly access Camunda’s APIs.
>   Usually, it is necessary to configure authentication, authorization
>   and also secure the connection to the REST API using SSL (HTTPS).
> - Web applications (Cockpit, Tasklist, …): similar considerations to the REST API apply.

In other words:

- Camunda is flexible with respect to authentication options
- It's *YOUR* responsibility to choose the appropriate authentication mechanism for your particular use case, and configure Camunda accordingly.

SUGGESTION: [Best practices for REST API security: Authentication and authorization](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/10/06/best-practices-for-authentication-and-authorization-for-rest-apis/)